# How do I make a specific error window when a zero or negative value is place a variable?

Tags: javascript

I was following a tutorial online to make a loan calculator. The calculator is properly working however I was trying to put an error window when you put zero or a negative number in one of the variables (you can't have a negative/zero loan amount, Interest rate, or Numbers of years). I want to be able to make a specific error window to say "You can not put a zero or negative number as a value for the loan amount" when a zero or negative number is put in the loan amount. And the same for the other variables where you can put in values if that makes any sense.
I was able to make an error window that pops up when the you open the calculator that says "You can not put any negative numbers or zeros" and this same window pops up whenever you put a zero or negative number. I tried to call the const of each variable and make the window pop up but that didn't work.

```
    document.getElementById("loan-form").addEventListener("submit", computeResults);

function computeResults(e) {
  // UI

  const UIamount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  const UIinterest = document.getElementById("interest").value;
  const UIyears = document.getElementById("years").value;
  hola(UIamount);
  hola(UIinterest);
  hola(UIyears);

  // Calculate

  const principal = parseFloat(UIamount);
  const CalculateInterest = parseFloat(UIinterest) / 100 / 12;
  const calculatedPayments = parseFloat(UIyears) * 12;

  //Compute monthly Payment

  const x = Math.pow(1 + CalculateInterest, calculatedPayments);
  const monthly = (principal * x * CalculateInterest) / (x - 1);
  const monthlyPayment = monthly.toFixed(2);

  //Compute Interest

  const totalInterest = (monthly *calculatedPayments - principal).toFixed(2);

  //Compute Total Payment

  const totalPayment = (monthly * calculatedPayments).toFixed(2);

  //Show results

  document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").innerHTML = "$" + monthlyPayment;

  document.getElementById("totalInterest").innerHTML = "%" + totalInterest;

  document.getElementById("totalPayment").innerHTML = "$" + totalPayment;

  e.preventDefault();
}
function hola(x) {
  console.log(x);
  if(x == 0) {
      document.getElementById("cont1").style.display="none";

  }

  if(x == 1) {
      document.getElementById("cont1").style.display="none";

  }

  if(x<=0)  {
      document.getElementById("cont1").style.display="block";

  }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't have the error come up when you try to put it into one of the variables. You'd have it come up when the user leaves the field where the data is entered. You need to add a `change` event handler to that field and simply do your validation there.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that you will have with your code is if one value is invalid but the others under it are valid, the error will be hidden.

Instead of a function just have an if statement:

```
const UIamount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
const UIinterest = document.getElementById("interest").value;
const UIyears = document.getElementById("years").value;
let err_box = document.getElementById("cont1");

err_box.style.display="none";//hide the popup first

if(UIamount <= 0 || UIinterest <= 0 || UIyears <= 0){
   err_box.style.display="block";
}
```